# getting rid of gap in html table

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I am getting a  gap at the end/beginning of just 2 cells in my email and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

The cell-padding is set to 0
cell-spacing = 0

Here's what I have:

```css
<style type="text/css">
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,h7 {
 font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 line-height: 1;}
h1 {
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #B99350;
 line-height: 1;
 font-size: 25px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 font-align: center;
 font-weight: normal;
 text-align: center;
}
h3{
 font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 line-height: 1;
 color: #B99350;
 font-size: 24px;
 padding-top: 15px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: capitalize;
}
h4{
 font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 line-height: 1;
 color: #b99350;
 font-size: 22px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 font-style: normal;
 text-align: left;
 font-weight: normal;
}
h5{
 font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 line-height: 1.3;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #FAFAFA;
 font-size: 14px;
 padding-top: 3px;
 color: #FCFCFC;
}
h6{
 font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 line-height: 1.3;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-size: 14px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}
h7 {
 font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 16px;
  padding-top: 3px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 padding-right: 20px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 line-height: 25px;
}
h8 {
 padding-left: 15px;}
 
 h9 {
 font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 10px;
  padding-top: 3px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 padding-right: 20px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 line-height: 25px;}
  
body,td,th {
 font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 16px;
  padding-top: 3px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 line-height: 20px;
}
li {
 font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 line-height: 1em;
 padding-top: 10px;
}
body {
 background-color: #FCFCFC;
}

.blue {
 color: #B99350;
}
</style>
```

```html
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" valign="center" ;
>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#201545" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse">
      <h7>• AA rated State Government of South Australia occupies 76% of the NLA</h7>
        <br>
          <h7>• $13 million* spent in refurbishments between 2008 and 2016</h7>
          <br>
          <h7>• 5.3 year WALE and 97% occupancy</h7>
          <br>
          <h7>• Located in the core of Adelaide’s CBD</h7>
          <br>
          <h7>• Surplus land area with development potential</h7>
          <br>
          <h7>• Fully leased net income of $9.3 million*</h7>
          <br>
          <h7>• Net lettable area of 19,855sqm*</h7>
          <br>
          <h7>• 4.5-Star NABERS Rating</h7>
  </p>
        <h7><strong>Please <a href="http://v3au.zone-secure.net/drive/4191/231302/" style="color:#ffffff">click here</a> to view the Information Memorandum
        <h7></strong><br>
        <h9>* approx </h9>
        <hr valign="top" width="100%" size="4px" color="#9D7F4A" align="left"  style="border-collapse: collapse;" >
<h4>FOR SALE VIA EXPRESSIONS OF INTEREST CLOSING 5PM (AEDT) THURSDAY, 20 OCTOBER 2016</h4></td>
    <tr><td valign="top" width="232" align="left" bgcolor="#201545" cellspacing="0" style="padding-left: 15px; ";><img src="JLL_Logo_Rev_WEB.png" width="97" height="42" alt="JLL"/>
        <h5><strong>Rob Sewell<br>
          </strong>+61 407 243 229<br>
         <a href="mailto:rob.sewell@ap.jll.com" style="color:#ffffff">rob.sewell@ap.jll.com</a></h5>
        <h5><strong>Jamie Guerra</strong><br>
          +61 418 849 780<br>
 <a href="mailto:jamie.guerra@ap.jll.com" style="color:#ffffff"> jamie.guerra@ap.jll.com</a></h5>
        <h5><strong>Roger Klem <br>
          </strong>+61 423 919 373<br>
        <a href="mailto:roger.klem@ap.jll.com" style="color:#ffffff"> roger.klem@ap.jll.com</a>
         <br>
         <br>
         <strong>INTERNATIONAL</strong><br>
          <strong>Stuart McCann<br>
          </strong>+65 8522 1031<br>
      <a href="mailto:stuart.mccann@ap.jll.com" style="color:#ffffff"> stuart.mccann@ap.jll.com</a></h5></td>
      <td valign="top" bgcolor="#201545" style="color: #2BACE2; padding-left: 15px;"><img src="KnightFrank_LR.png" alt="KnightFrank" width="108" height="54"/>
        <h5><strong>Guy Bennett<br>
          </strong>+61 418 808 548<br>
          <<a href="mailto:guy.bennett@au.knightfrank.com" style="color:#ffffff"> guy.bennett@au.knightfrank.com</a></h5>
        <h5><strong>Lukas Weeks</strong><br>
          +61 434 957 537<br>
  <a href="mailto:lukas.weeks@au.knightfrank.com" style="color:#ffffff"> lukas.weeks@au.knightfrank.com</a></h5>
        <h5><strong>James Parry</strong><br>
          + 61 408 553 000<br>
 <a href="mailto:james.parry@au.knightfrank.com" style="color:#ffffff"> james.parry@au.knightfrank.com</a>
<br>
<br>
<strong>INTERNATIONAL</strong><br>
  <strong>Neil Brookes<br>
  </strong>+65 8309 4985<br>
 <a href="mailto:neil.brookes@asia.knightfrank.com" style="color:#ffffff"> neil.brookes@asia.knightfrank.com</a></h5></td>
      </tbody>
</table></tr>
</body>
</html>
```

There are 2 columns/cells in this section and both are sitting with a massive gap between the (missing) logos and the text above it and I can't figure out how to close it... 
Please help!
Thanks

P.S. the top code is not to the end. But I wasn't allowed to show the rest as it was "too much HTML" not enough question...

Comment: It would be better to separate your css from your html. While you do that, create a code snippet so we can visually see the issue.

Comment: Thanks Derk, I am new here, and didn't know I could do that... Now i do. So have updated my post to be a bit more user friendly... hope it makes a bit more sense now and someone can possibly shed some light as to why I am getting this gap!!

Comment: Good job! Now we can see more :)

Answer (score 0):

I HAVE THE ANSWER -

at the very end the

is after  &  and should be before them.

Simple as that. Swapped it in front and all fixed!

Answer (score -1):

First of all, this is NOT how you use tables!
[W3Schools Tables Link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)

Secondly, the space after each email field is the margin for the h5 tag. See that all your data is wrapped in an h5 tag? Those provide a top-bottom margin. Try removing it to see the effects. You cant call these "cells" because you are not wrapping the individual items in td tags.

Also, dont forget to close your tables.

Comment: Thanks, this is not the complete html.. it would not let me include the whole lot...So i included as much as I could that was relevant...

Comment: the table is closed further down the code... and the problem I am having isn't with the email addresses & names... they are how I want them to be... 

The problem I having is directly above the logos - so above this block of code: 
'code'<tr><td valign="top" width="232" align="left" bgcolor="#201545" cellspacing="0" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-top:13px;";><h5><img src="../../ASSETS/JLL Logos/JLL_Logo_Rev_WEB.png" width="100" height="44" alt="JLL"/></h5> 'code'

which actually is between 2 cell rows... the top spans 2 columns, then below is 2 columns.